# Confusion between Layered rendering and Multiple Render Targets in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, glsl

If I bind individual layers of a texture array (`GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY`) to different color attachment points (e.g I am binding the 4 layers of texture array 'textureName' to color attachments 0,1,2 and 3):

```
glFramebufferTextureLayer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 + 0, textureName, 0, 0);
glFramebufferTextureLayer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 + 1, textureName, 0, 1);
glFramebufferTextureLayer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 + 2, textureName, 0, 2);
glFramebufferTextureLayer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 + 3, textureName, 0, 3);
```

And in the geometry shader , I use `gl_Layer` to assign vertices to different layers. (I am just duplicating geometry)

2 Followup questions:

**Case 1:**
My Fragment shader writes to only first color buffer. (location = 0.)

What do the 4 layers of texture array contain at end of the program execution? Did geometry duplication occur (because of using `gl_Layer`) or the last 3 textures are blank(because I did not write to other color buffers in fragment shader)?

**Case 2:**
I write to all 4 color buffers in the fragment shader (location = 0, 1, 2, 3)

What do the 4 layers of texture array contain at end of the program execution?

By these 2 cases, I am trying to understand if layered rendering has any impact on multiple render targets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In either case, you invoke undefined behavior because `gl_Layer` is out of bounds. Therefore the contents of any of the attachments is undefined. It may be anything, most likely the clear color.

If you own a copy of 8th edition of "The Red Book", see pages 556 to 558.

The reason is that you *do not* use layered rendering at all. What `glFramebufferTextureLayer(..., n)` is doing is bind a **single** layer of an array texture.

You're doing this 4 times, binding 4 single layers of one texture (but that's irrelevant, this could as well be 4 individual, normal textures) to 4 attachments, unlayered. You need `glFramebufferTexture`, not `glFramebufferTextureLayer`.

On the other hand, you're writing 4 different values to `gl_Layer` when in reality there is only one layer.